# A similar (little) Fermat's Theorem result and repunit multiple

Tags: arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle, repunit-numbers

I got this exercise in arithmetic class (I'm a french student but let me translate the problem)
[image: Original problem] In this thread I only talk about questions from question 2) on the paper.

> Let n and p be 2 integers greater or equal than 2 such that $gcd(n,p)=1$. We
> want to show that there is $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $n^k \equiv 1\mod  p  $.
> (I find this closed to De Fermat's little theorem)
>
> Q1) Find the smallest k for n=4 and p=7
>
> Q2) If p is prime say something about the existence of k
>
> Q3) *p is no more prime* Let $r_k$ be the rest of the division
> algorithm of $n^k$ by $p$. Show that there is two positive and
> different integers i and j such that $r_i =r_j$
>
> Q4) We suppose that $i<j$ . Show that $n^{j-i} \equiv 1 \mod p$
>
> Let n be an odd number that doesn't end by 5.
>
> Q5) Show that $gcd(9n;10)=1$
>
> Q6) Show that there is a multiple of n which
> is a repunit number (base 10)
> Q7) With n=101 find a multiple of n
> which is a repunit (give your approach)

With the pigeonhole principle I answered Q3. For Q4 I calculate $n^{j-i} -1 $ but I don't find any whole numbers times p which give me  $n^{j-i} -1 $.

*(I don't know if it's the same symbol for english but '^' stands for the gcd)*

For Q5) there is only 4 cases :

$n \equiv 1 \mod 10$

$n \equiv 3 \mod 10$

$n \equiv 7 \mod 10$

$n \equiv 9 \mod 10$

From that that's easy to show that $gcd(9n,10)=1.$

For the Q6) we got the same hypothesis from last proof now we have (9n)^10=1. So it exists an integer l such that $(9n)^l \equiv 1 \mod 10$.
Then there is k in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$ (9n)^l = 10k+1$$
I know that for $n \geq 2 $ we have $9U_n = 10^n -1$ with Un the nth repunit number in base 10.
But maybe this is obvious but I don't manage to show that there is a multiple of n which is a repunit number (always base 10).

So if you can help me with this problem, please.

(For Q7 with a smalll python programm I've got 101*11 is a repunit number)

**EDIT 1** I changed the french notation to be more comprehensible

Comment: Yes, the carat ^ is not used as a gcd operation in english notation, instead often showing it as a function $\gcd(x,y)$; the use of [] for the modulus is not really used either, rather $\bmod n$ is appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q4,
\begin{align*}
n^i n^{j-i} = n^j \equiv n^i &\mod p\\
\implies n^i(n^{j-i}-1) \equiv 0 &\mod p
\end{align*}
using the fact that $\operatorname{gcd}(n,p)=1$ you should be able to finish from there.

For Q6, applying the result the other way (taking $10$ to the power instead of $9n$) yields
$$10^k -1 \equiv 0 \mod 9n,$$ which bears a closer resemblance to the formula you want to apply. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you, I solved Q4 using Gauss' Lemma (or Gauss theorem) and which gives me that $p$ divides $n^{j-i}$ . For Q6 we have all the hypothesis and $10^k -1$ is a decimal repunit